# Error of implicit coercion on a TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I think i have the most common actionscript error.In the code below i have a MovieClip with some TextFields inside and i want to animate them.When i assign the class to the MovieClip i get this error `1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.text:TextField.`. When i `trace` the childs i get `[Object TextField]` and the code works fine if i place it on the first frame and apply it to a Dynamic Text so why i get this error when i try to apply this code to the childs of a MovieClip ?

Is there a chance to have forgot to `import` any necessary library ?

I have made the TextFields dynamic,i have embed the characters and set anti-alias for animation.

```
package AScripts
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flupie.textanim.*;

public class TextFade extends MovieClip {
    private var child : Object;

    public function TextFade( )     
    {
        /*    for (var i : int = 0; i < numChildren; i++  )  {
              child = getChildAt( i );
              trace( child );  
        */
            child = getChildAt( 0 );
            var txtanim:TextAnim = new TextAnim( child ); // <-- Error
                            /* TextAnim expects a TextField as argument */
            txtanim.mode = TextAnimMode.RANDOM;
            txtanim.split = TextAnimSplit.WORDS;
            txtanim.effects = myEffect;
            txtanim.start();
    }
    function myEffect( block:TextAnimBlock ) : void
    {
        TweenLite.to( block , .5 , {alpha : 0 , delay : Math.random( ) * 1 } );
    }   
  }
}
```

UPDATE : I made the suggestion changes and worked.

```
import flash.text.*;
private var child : TextField;
child = getChildAt( i ) as TextField;
```

Comment: you have child casted as an object. If TextAnim is expecting a text field, cast it as a textfield. see if that works

Comment: If i change `private var child : Object;` to `private var child : TextField;` i get `Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TextField.` error.

Comment: you need to do `import flash.text.*;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
try 
{
    // Need to explicitly cast the child to TextField otherwise
    // we are making an implicit cast and will get an error.
    var textField:TextField = child as TextField; 
    var txtanim:TextAnim = new TextAnim( textField); 
} 
catch (error) 
{
    // unable to cast to a textfield, handle this error if necessary.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast child as an Object when you get the object or change the declaration of the child var:

```
// cast as TextField
public function TextFade( )     
{
    child = getChildAt( 0 ) as Object;
    // ... rest of method


// change declaration of child
public class TextFade extends MovieClip {
    private var child : TextField;
```